# Python Pandas: Doing cumsum for each day for months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I have a data frame which is as below

```
Storeid      Year-Month     Date        Amount
 111           01-2016    2016-01-29      10
 111           01-2016    2016-01-30      15
 111           02-2016    2016-02-03      20
 111           02-2016    2016-02-10      17
 111           02-2016    2016-02-15      18
 111           03-2016    2016-03-02      12
 112           01-2016    2016-01-25      14
 112           01-2016    2016-01-29      12
 ...
```

What I want as an output is this

```
Storeid      Year-Month     Date        Amount
 111           01-2016    2016-01-29      10
 111           01-2016    2016-01-30      25
 111           02-2016    2016-02-03      20
 111           02-2016    2016-02-10      37
 111           02-2016    2016-02-15      55
 111           03-2016    2016-03-02      12
 112           01-2016    2016-01-25      14
 112           01-2016    2016-01-29      26
 ...
```

The value is reset after each month and again starts with 0. I tried doing a `cumsum` function from pandas but, it tries to do it across the entire data frame. How do I restrict it to do for each month?

Goal is to find "Given a date, which store reached their sales target as of that date for the month". Sales target is $1000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `groupby.cumsum`:

```
df['AmountToDate'] = df.groupby(['Storeid', 'Year-Month']).Amount.cumsum()
df
```

[image]

*Update*: To extract the corresponding rows, you can use `groupby.apply(...cumsum..)` which allows you to do more customized operations:

```
(df.groupby(['Storeid', 'Year-Month'], as_index=False, group_keys=False)
 .apply(lambda g: g.assign(Amount = g.Amount.cumsum())[lambda x: x.Amount >= 25].head(1)))
```

[image]

*How this works?*

- The `groupby.apply` means the `lambda` expression inside the `apply` method is applied to each group (here unique combination of Storeid and Year-Month) separately;
- The parameter g passed to lambda expression is a sub data frame with unique storeid + Year-Month(group variable), for each data frame calculate `Amount` cumsum, and filter out rows where the cumsum >= target and take the first row with `head(1)`.

Comment: Thanks @psidom. This works. But, how do I filter the date on which target was reached? For example, in above example, If my target is >=25 I would only want row 1, row 3, row 7.

Comment: Just updated with a method to extract the corresponding rows.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. I am still learning Pandas. Do you mind adding some more description in the answer about how customized script works?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the edit. Last question. As per http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html , it says that `group_keys` should be `True` when using `apply`. We have this as `False`. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Yes the default is True, which adds extra columns to the result. I set it to False so as to keep the result as clean, but it's just a parameter you can adjust depending on what you want the result to be.